# Why does my form shows nothing but i still have the code from my design view and my form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

This is my form design view
[image]

This is my code from design mode[image]

This is my code from the form
[image]

Any solution to solve this ?

Comment: Why tagging vs code and vs 2017? Is this project developed on those IDE and you migrate it to vs 2022? Are you upgrading the framework version too?

Comment: @Martheen sorry my bad, I have removed the tags. I developed it in vs 2022 but when i try to look in my design view for this form, the design is blank. However the codes from the designer are still there and the controls reference are still useable.

Comment: So you originally drag and drop the controls in design view, then it is suddenly gone now, or do you hand-code the designer.vb from the beginning?

Comment: @Martheen i use drag and drop

Comment: Can't replicate this on my VS 2022 install with new VB.NET WinForm project. Can you replicate this bug on new project? If not, try adding the customization from your problematic project until you can replicate them, then update your question with it https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If you really drop controls, then the `InitializeComponent` method should call  `Controls.Add(..)` or `Controls.AddRange(...)` to add the controls. I can't see that line in the second image. In the third image, you have in the ctor a commented line `Me.Controls.AddRange(...)`. So you are doing something wrong. Check the Document Outline window or see what you have in `Controls` collection at runtime. Nothing.

Comment: You seem to have made a mess of that code yourself. You have a method named `RegistrationForm` That calls `InitializeComponent`. That sems to be mimicking a C# constructor. It may be that a VS bug has deleted the contents of that `InitializeComponent` method but you seem to have done plenty of damage yourself. Regardless, you're going to need to either re-add the code to `InitializeComponent` yourself or else delete all the fields that refer to controls and components from the designer code file and then add all the controls and components to the designer again.

Comment: yeah fortunately i saved a copy of my vb project and i just delete the form and import the existing form from my backup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah fortunately i saved a copy of my vb project and i just delete the form and import the existing form from my backup